# Geb picking a link from a list

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

I have recently been reading through the book of Geb and trying to get to grips with it as it seems like a great tool. I feel like I'm getting there but there's still some really core concepts that I can't seem to grasp.

As an example, take the website:-
 http://www.escapistmagazine.com/videos/view/zero-punctuation

Now if I want to test that the first video listed links to the correct page my first thought was to do the following

```
class ZeroPunctuationIndexPage extends Page {
    static url = "http://www.escapistmagazine.com/videos/view/zero-punctuation"
    static at = {title == "Zero Punctuation Video Gallery | The Escapist"}
    static content = {

        selectFirstVideo {$("a", 0, class: "filmstrip_video")}
        firstVideoTitle {$("i", 0, class: "filmstrip_video")}

    }
}

class ZeroPunctuationIndexSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

    def "Click the latest video and play it"(){
        given:
        to ZeroPunctuationIndexPage

        when:
        selectFirstVideo.click()

        then:
        title.endsWith(firstVideoTitle)

    }
}
```

Essentially I thought if I pick the first class that contains the video (filmstrip_video) and then pick the link inside it then I could click that, and compare the video title from the link to the new page title.

Looking at it again I'm not surprised it didn't work, but I'm not sure what to do.

If anyone could give me a quick solution i'd appreciate it. I'm not doing anything in particular with the escapist page, I just picked somewhere with an index of videos to try out writing a test.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not getting the link and it was failing, so I fixed that and double checked. Now, it's working fine and it passes. Also, when you are selecting the first element, you don't need to write 0 explicitly as by default it will choose the 0th element.

```
class ZeroPunctuationIndexPage extends Page {
    static url = "http://www.escapistmagazine.com/videos/view/zero-punctuation"
    static at = {title == "Zero Punctuation Video Gallery | The Escapist"}
    static content = {

        selectFirstVideo {$("div.filmstrip_video").find('a')}
        firstVideoTitle {$("div.filmstrip_video").find('i')}

    }
}


class ZeroPunctuationIndexSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

        def "Click the latest video and play it"(){
            given:
            to ZeroPunctuationIndexPage

            when:
            waitFor { selectFirstVideo.click() }

            then:
            title.endsWith(firstVideoTitle.text())

        }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Makes so much more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
title.endsWith(firstVideoTitle.text())
```

I'm on my iPad, so I can't test it, but it should work.

Comment: The code is failing at the 

selectFirstVideo {$("a", 0, class: "filmstrip_video")}

So it's not getting to the title part at all :/